# EF Code First: Add row to table with a non-identity primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

To reduce this problem to a simple version, I've created this table:

```
create table TestTable(id int primary key, descr varchar(50))
```

Note that the `id` field is not an identity field.  Now, if I try to use EF Code First to insert a row:

```
[Table("TestTable")]
public class TestTable
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descr { get; set; }
}

public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) {}
    public DbSet<TestTable> TestTables { get; set; }
}

static void Main()
{
    const string connectionString = "...";
    using (var db = new TestContext(connectionString))
    {
        db.TestTables.Add(new TestTable { id = 42, descr = "hallo" });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The result is an exception:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'TestTable';
>   column does not allow nulls.

But the code that inserts the row specifies `id = 42`.  Any clue or hint welcome.

Comment: Did you try removing the `[Key]` attribute?

Comment: @hunter: Yes I have, results in the same error.  I suspsect EF implicitly assumes a column ending in `Id` is a key.

Comment: Try using this DataAnotations option `[DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`

Comment: @Guillelon: Neat, that looks like it works!  Will test some more.  You forgot `.Schema.` btw, the full name is `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`

Comment: @Andomar Yes sorry I was just about to edit it and put it like this `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` ;) hope it works!!

Comment: @Guillelon: It works, care to put it in an answer?  I can also delete the question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just add this **DataAnnotations** `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` and the libraries

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("TestTable")]
public class TestTable
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descr { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity were used but the table key column is still int (not identity) will EF core generate a new int primary key value? (or will it give an exception)